# Decorate existing class to support javafx properties

Tags: java, javafx, decorator

I have an existing class, that I want to keep ignorant of javafx. Is there a generally accepted way to decorate or adapt it so that it supports javafx properties?

I want to do something like the following (which is obviously wrong):

```
public class FooWrapper {
    /**
     * Decorates a Foo instance with javafx stuff
     */
    private final Foo foo;

    public FooWrapper(Foo toWrap) {
        this.foo = toWrap;
    }

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return this.foo.getName();//?????
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return this.nameProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setFirstName(final String name) {
        this.nameProperty().set(name);
    }

}

public class Foo {
    /**
     * Basic class I want to keep ignorant of javafx
     */

    private String name = "hello";

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the classes in the [`javafx.beans.property.adapter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/adapter/package-summary.html) package.

```
public class Foo {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

```
public class FooAdapter {

    private final JavaBeanStringProperty name;

    public FooAdapter(Foo foo) {
        try {
            name = JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder.create().bean(foo).name("name").build();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    public final void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

The adapter property, as created above, requires that the underlying object follows the Java Bean convention for properties. However, there are ways to customize what methods to use for getters/setters.

The adapter property will get the value from the underlying object and, if writable, also write to the underlying object when updated. It can also observe the underlying object for changes if it supports `PropertyChangeListener`s. Note that this functionality is implemented using reflection; if you are using modules you need to add the appropriate `exports`/`opens` directives to your `module-info` (see the javadoc of the various properties, such as [`JavaBeanStringProperty`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/adapter/JavaBeanStringProperty.html), for details).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, from just reading now, the "Java Bean naming convention" means that the constructor has to take no arguments. I guess that in this case it's just referring to the getter and setter names and signatures though. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the focus is on getters/setters. Edited to make that clearer.

Comment: if the field is read-only, do i need a corresponding `ReadOnlyJavaBean*Property`, or is there no need?

Comment: You need to use the `ReadOnlyJavaBeanXXXProperty`s (via the corresponding builder classes) because the non-read-only builder will look for a setter method, throwing an exception since one doesn't exist. Besides that, you should use the read-only versions anyway as it more accurately adapts the underlying object (why say a property is writable when it's not?).

Comment: what about if the underlying class member is a List<>. Do I use JavaBeanObjectProperty? Or do I roll my own with an ObserverList and SimpleListProperty?

Comment: You could use a `JavaBeanObjectProperty`. Unless you can implement observing the underlying collection/map for structural changes I'd say rolling your own is overkill.